# What Is The Error In JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to click on links to add it to select with checking if there is the  item was not in list before menu but It seems loop part has some issue.

**JavaScript code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.link').click(function(event) {
  var this_item_was_not_in_list = true;
  var item =$(this).text();
  for (var i = 0; i < $('#list').length; i++) {
   if ($('#list').options[i].text == item) { this_item_was_not_in_list = false; break;};
  };

  if (this_item_was_not_in_list) {$('#list').append('<option>' + item + '</option>')};

        
 });
});
```

**HTML Code**

```html
 <a href="#" class="link">Bread</a>
 <a href="#" class="link">Suger</a>
 <a href="#" class="link">Tea</a>

 <select id="list">  
       
 </select>
```

Comment: A problem that when i click items , an error happen in list . try it here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/MohamedMaher/acngd2de/)

Comment: because you are mixing native methods and jQuery for too much ...use one or the other. Read the errors. `$('#list').options` is invalid for a jQuery object and then you try to apply a jQuery method `text()` to native elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways to simplify this using jQuery methods.

One example:

```
$('.link').click(function(event) {
     var item = $(this).text();
     if(!$('#list option[value=' + item +']').length){
       $('#list').append('<option value="' + item +'">' + item + '</option>');
     }
});
```

Instead of using your `for` loop can easily iterate over a collection of elements using `each()` which exposes the index and the element

Answer (score 0):

Where you are doing:

`for (var i = 0; i < $('#list').length; i++) {`

You should be doing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('#list option').length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#list').options[i].text == item)
```

Aren't some parenthesis missing?

```
if ($('#list').options[i].text() == item)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problen is here:

```
$('#list').options[i].text == item
```

That is not the way to get `option` elements from the `select` element.

Try this:

```
$('#list').find('options:nth(' + i + ')')).text() == item
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6n4kxsz/) for this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.link').click(function(event) {
        var this_item_was_not_in_list = true;
        var clickedItemName =$(this).text();
        var listLength = $('#list option').length;
         
        for (i=0; i<listLength ; i++)
        {
            if ($('#list option')[i].value == clickedItemName)
            { 
                this_item_was_not_in_list = false; 
                break;
            }
        }
        if (this_item_was_not_in_list) 
        {
            $('#list').append('<option>' + clickedItemName + '</option>');
        }     
    });
});
```

```html
<html>      
    <a href="#" class="link">Bread</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Sugar</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Tea</a>

    <select id="list"></select> 

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```